# Can I extend short wiring for an RV outlet replacement?

Tags: wiring, receptacle

We have an outdoor outlet that is busted and needs to be replaced. The wiring is on the short side and for a new outlet the wiring will be too short.

Can I splice in a new wire to match to the existing wire with a wire nut or something or do I need to run a new wire?

The outlet is a 30-amp outlet for an RV hook up, I have plenty of wire left over from the original install for either option, and I am confident I can do the hands-on work, but I don't know the best way or the science and reasoning why it would be the best way.
thank you

Comment: If the wire reaches the original outlet, why would it not reach a replacement outlet?

Comment: Turn off the breaker, remove the cover plate, unscrew the receptacle and pull it as far out of the wall as the wires will allow. Take a picture with a ruler showing just how far that is, [edit] the picture into your question and someone here will be able to help you out. Most likely, you'll be fine as replacement like-for-like doesn't require code updates.

Comment: It depends on where you hope to splice. Inside the box? Can the box be remounted in a slightly different location to gain available wire length? Photos would be great.